# How to Stop Navigation If user enters wrong password?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to stop navigation if user enters wrong password. My App is still redirecting after catching error. I have tried this simple If condition But It doesn't seem to work.

```
login = (email,password)=>{
    try{
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(function(user){
            console.log(user)
        }); 
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error.toString())
if(error===true) { 
    return; //stop the execution of function
}
    }
        this.props.navigation.replace('Home')
}
```

Comment: Why do you navigate outside of promise callback?
I think navigation should rely on auth response, so it should be placed in `then` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, do like this.. I think, no need to write extra try catch

```
login = (email,password)=>{

const nav = this.props.navigation;
  
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then( user => {
            console.log(user)
             nav.replace('Home')
        }). catch( error => {
             console.log(error) 
       }) 
    
        
}
```

Comment: Hi is this the correct answer? i tried doing this but it still direct me to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Your version is correct but `error` is not boolean so you can't check if it is `=== true` but you can check if it exist by simply doing `if (error)` and it should work

```js
login = (email,password)=>{
    try {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(function(user){
            console.log(user)
        }); 
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.toString())
        if(error) { 
          return; //stop the execution of function
        }
    }
    this.props.navigation.replace('Home')
}
```

Comment: Still navigating to next screen and then I get the error ( Error: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password. )